# Fetching data from excel in R

Tags: r

When i try to run the `sqlFetch` statement, i get the following error intermittently.

```
Error in odbcTableExists(channel, sqtable) : 
  ‘Sheet20’: table not found on channel
```

Comment: Fetching data directly from Excel is hard, couldn't you just export your data to .csv format?

Comment: I agree with @Stijn that it's hard to import data from excel, but not always. Can we see an example of the data (a screenshot of a sheet, perhaps)?

Comment: you could use the `read.xlsx` function of the `xlsx` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`odbcTableExists` is an internal function of the `RODBC` package. This line of code

```
  if (abort && !ans) 
    stop(sQuote(tablename), ": table not found on channel")
```

means there is a problem with the table name (obviously). Double check the case of the table name, even if sql statements are not case sensitive R is!

If it is not the problem try to the `read.xls` function from `gdata` package. It relies on a Perl library to convert excel spreadsheet to csv and then makes a call to `read.table`. This mean that you'll be able to pass to `read.xls` any parameters that you'd give to `read.table`, which is very useful sometimes.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend having a look at [XLConnect](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html) or one of the other Excel interface packages if you're unhappy with ODBC.